# Запрос к базе данных iCloud с подгрузкой данных

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Ребят, помогите исправить запрос, уже много часов над ним сижу, не пойму что не так. В моей базе хранится около 300 элементов и грузить их сразу не вариант, пытаюсь грузить по частям. Использую UiCollectionView. При загрузке определенного числа элементов, пытаюсь использовать curcor, но он работает не корректно, всего один раз подгружает данные и сразу, а хотелось загружать постепенно, когда пользователь пролистал страницу до конца. Привожу мой код, посоветуйте, что лучше: этот код доработать (я имею ввиду cursor) или отлавливать каждый элемен при прокрутке страницу и тем самый создать scrolling?

```
func getRecordsFromCloud() {
    restaurants = []

    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: self.DB, predicate: predicate)

    var queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["TrumbImage", "image"]
    queryOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh
    queryOperation.resultsLimit = 14
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
        if let restaurantRecord = record {
            self.restaurants.append(restaurantRecord)
            let imageAsset = restaurantRecord.objectForKey("TrumbImage") as! CKAsset

            self.sizeImage.append(UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL:imageAsset.fileURL)!)!.size)
        }
    }

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { [unowned self] (cursor, error) in

        if cursor != nil {
            println("there is more data to fetch")
            var newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
            newOperation.desiredKeys = ["TrumbImage", "image"]
            newOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh

            newOperation.resultsLimit = 3
            newOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
                if var restaurantRecord = record {
                    self.restaurants.append(restaurantRecord)
                    var imageAsset = restaurantRecord.objectForKey("TrumbImage") as! CKAsset

                    self.sizeImage.append(UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL:imageAsset.fileURL)!)!.size)
                }
            }

            newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock
            publicDatabase.addOperation(newOperation)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })

        }


    }

    publicDatabase.addOperation(queryOperation)


}
```

Comment: Объясните, почему закрываете вопрос?